# child elements won't acquire space according to the weights specified in android sdk

Tags: android

I can't get the textviews with text "15%" and "18%" to take up 50 % of space of the parent horizontal linear layout in spite of setting weights as 1 , layout-width as "0dp" and everything else that can be done(setting the parent weightsum=2 or setting the font smaller ) .None of the solution specified in similar previous questions has solved my problem It somehow wont work thoroughly googled the problem none of the solution works here is a pastebin http://pastebin.com/FyzHX7Gn which shows partial code

here is a snapshot of emulator I don't have a phone to test on so cant say if it works on phone or not.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextViews' parent should match whole display width. This might help you:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_row="2"
   android:layout_column="1"
   android:id="@+id/percentLinearLayout"
   android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
   android:weightSum="2"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView                                         
       android:layout_width="0px"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Medium"
       android:text="@string/fifteen_percent"
       android:id="@+id/percent15TextView"
       android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
       android:layout_width="0px"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
       android:text="@string/eighteen_percent"
       android:id="@+id/percentCustomTextView"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:numeric="integer" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: With this the second textview goes out of bounds cuz linear layout goes out of bounds

Comment: What do you mean with "out of bounds"? What bounds?

Comment: well it assumes the width of the parent i.e the grid not the cell (not sure) and hence the width becomes more that of the cell because of match-parent I presume

Comment: Can you add picture what show us what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: well I achieved what I wanted the out of bounds does not affect anything hence thou answer shall be accepted

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/percentLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Medium"
            android:text="@string/fifteen_percent"
            android:id="@+id/percent15TextView"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/percentCustomTextView"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:numeric="integer"
            android:text="@string/eighteen_percent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>
```